# Unable to inject aurelia-validation

Tags: dependency-injection, aurelia

I am getting the following error when trying to load a class that has validation injected into it.

> key/value cannot be null or undefined. Are you trying to
>   inject/register something that doesn't exist with DI?

I installed validation using jspm and I have verified using Chrome dev tools that the javascript for aurelia-validation is loaded (/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-validation@0.8.1/XXX.js - there are several js files in the folder loaded in Chrome). Removing `Validation` from the `@inject` and 'constructor', the class loads just fine.

Here is the code...

```
import {Repository} from 'repository';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';
import {Validation} from 'aurelia-validation';

@inject(Repository, Router, Validation)
export class Login {
    constructor(rep, router, validation) {
        this.rep = rep; 
        this.router = router;
        console.log('Login');

        this.login = {
            EmailAddress: '',
            Password: '',
            Password2: ''
        };

    }

    createAccount() {
        console.log('Create Account');
        this.router.navigateToRoute('verify');
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm new to JSPM, NPM, Aurelia, ES2016, and all the other tools in the Aurelia skeleton app, so I'm not sure where to start with this.

Comment: I can definitely see the value in having a MS project template for Aurelia. The Aurelia skeleton app installed over 400MB of files into the project file and you have to run command-line tools in order to get anything to work. I'm used to having VS just handle everything automatically. I'm still not sure why people think the NPM/JSPM stuff is so great, but I'll play along for now :).

Comment: I'd like to see two VS projects, one for Aurelia web apps and the other for Aurelia/Cordova apps. In my mind, those are the two most commercial scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aurelia-validation plugin has been rewritten recently and the validation API has changed again with respect to the accepted answer.

It is now using 2 separate libraries aurelia-validation and aurelia-validatejs. Validators do not seem to exist anymore and have been replaced by ValidationControllers.

The new API description and some examples can be found here:

http://blog.durandal.io/2016/06/14/new-validation-alpha-is-here/

.... and a working gist can be found here:

https://gist.run/?id=381fdb1a4b0865a4c25026187db865ce

The usage can be summarized in the code below:

```
import {inject, NewInstance} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';
import {ValidationController, validateTrigger} from 'aurelia-validation';
import {required, email, ValidationRules} from 'aurelia-validatejs';

@inject(NewInstance.of(ValidationController))
export class RegistrationForm {
  firstName = '';
  lastName = '';
  email = '';

  constructor(controller) {
    this.controller = controller;      
    // the default mode is validateTrigger.blur but 
    // you can change it:
    // controller.validateTrigger = validateTrigger.manual;
    // controller.validateTrigger = validateTrigger.change;
  }

  submit() {
    let errors = this.controller.validate();
    // todo: call server...
  }

  reset() {
    this.firstName = '';
    this.lastName = '';
    this.email = '';
    this.controller.reset();
  }
}


ValidationRules
  .ensure('firstName').required()
  .ensure('lastName').required()
.ensure('email').required().email()
.on(RegistrationForm);
```

---

Hope this helps.

EDIT: This has changed, apparently validatejs was a temporary solution.

[This article](http://www.sobell.net/aurelia-validation/) explains how it all works now. If you used validatejs you will also have to update your ValidationRenderer. This gist shows the updated version of the renderer in use: https://gist.run/?id=1d612b3ae341c7e9c12113e1771988e7

Here is a snippet of the code coming from the blog if the link dies:

```
import {inject, NewInstance} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {ValidationRules, ValidationController} from "aurelia-validation";

@inject(NewInstance.of(ValidationController))
export class App {

  message = '';
  firstname: string = '';
  lastname: string = '';

  constructor(private controller: ValidationController) {
    ValidationRules
      .ensure((m: App) => m.lastname).displayName("Surname").required()
      .ensure((m: App) => m.firstname).displayName("First name").required()
      .on(this);
  }

  validateMe() {
    this.controller
      .validate()
      .then(v => {
        if (v.length === 0)
          this.message = "All is good!";
        else
          this.message = "You have errors!";
      })
  }
}
```

... and the new validation renderer:

```
import {
  ValidationRenderer,
  RenderInstruction,
  ValidationError
} from 'aurelia-validation';

export class BootstrapFormRenderer {
  render(instruction) {
    for (let { error, elements } of instruction.unrender) {
      for (let element of elements) {
        this.remove(element, error);
      }
    }

    for (let { error, elements } of instruction.render) {
      for (let element of elements) {
        this.add(element, error);
      }
    }
  }

  add(element, error) {
    const formGroup = element.closest('.form-group');
    if (!formGroup) {
      return;
    }

    // add the has-error class to the enclosing form-group div
    formGroup.classList.add('has-error');

    // add help-block
    const message = document.createElement('span');
    message.className = 'help-block validation-message';
    message.textContent = error.message;
    message.id = `validation-message-${error.id}`;
    formGroup.appendChild(message);
  }

  remove(element, error) {
    const formGroup = element.closest('.form-group');
    if (!formGroup) {
      return;
    }

    // remove help-block
    const message = formGroup.querySelector(`#validation-message-${error.id}`);
    if (message) {
      formGroup.removeChild(message);

      // remove the has-error class from the enclosing form-group div
      if (formGroup.querySelectorAll('.help-block.validation-message').length === 0) {
        formGroup.classList.remove('has-error');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Haven't had a chance to review this yet, but I'm aware that the validation for Aurelia has changed and this looks like a more accurate answer than my own so I'll mark it as the answer for now. Considering this is considered an alpha release (to my understanding anyway), I am guessing the answer will need to evolve as updates are released.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this blog post](http://blog.durandal.io/2016/05/10/aurelia-releases-may-10-2016/), the validation code has changed.

I ended up calling `jspm install aurelia-validatejs` and then changing my code to this...

```
import {Repository} from 'repository';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';
import {Validator} from 'aurelia-validatejs';

@inject(Repository, Router)
export class Login {
    constructor(rep, router) {
        this.rep = rep; 
        this.router = router;
        console.log('Login');

        this.login = {
            EmailAddress: '',
            Password: '',
            Password2: ''
        };

        this.validator = new Validator(this.login);
        this.validator.ensure('EmailAddress')
                .required();
    }

    createAccount() {
        console.log('Create Account');
        // Not sure how to actually validate yet. Before you would call
        // this.validator.validate().then, but validate doesn't appear to
        // return a promise anymore. Still looking into this.
    }

}
```

Note that the import has changed as well as how you create the Validator (it is not injected).